# Which hold has the most giant camps?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As an aspiring Giant and Mammoth poacher/hunter I would appreciate knowing which hold has the most camps.

I know both `Whiterun` Hold and `Eastmarch` have large numbers of Giants, Mammoths and Giant Camps, but I was wondering which has the most camps?

Answer (score 3):

Giant camps are common across Skyrim

The holds with the most camps is actually a tie between `The pale` and `Whiterun`, which both have 4 known Giant camps.

`Hjaalmarch` hold has one, and `Eastmarch` hold has three.

`The Pale`
- Blizzard Rest
- Red Road Pass
- Stonehill Bluff
- Tumble Arch Pass

`Whiterun`
- Bleakwind Basin
- Guldun Rock
- Secunda's Kiss
- Sleeping Tree Camp

`Hjaalmarch` 
- Talking Stone Camp

`Eastmarch`
- Broken Limb Camp
- Cradlecrush Rock
- Steamcrag Camp

Here is a map from the [elderscrolls.wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/File:Giant_Camps.png) detailing the locations on a Skyrim map.[image: Giant Camps in Skyrim]